# Limiting a signal by multiplying it by an array

Tags: matlab, math, plot, octave

I'm trying to limit a signal by multiplying the signal by an array to limit the amplitude within a certain range.  The signal in **(green) the tot array** isn't suppose to go past the limiting array in **(red) the ptest array**, but it does, *how can I fix this so the green signal doesn't go past the red line (ptest array)*? see code and plot below.  **Please note this is a simple test the signals will be more complicated.**

I'm using octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab

[image: plot]

```
fs=200
x=[0,.2,.5,1]
y=[1,.5,.1,0]

t=linspace(0,x(end),fs);
peq=polyfit(x,y,length(y)); %create polynomial from points

ptest=polyval(peq,t); %plug numbers into polynomial
plot(ptest,t,'-ro') 
hold on 
plot(x,y,'b*')

t2=linspace(0,2*pi,fs);
s1 = sin(10*t2) ; %signal to limit
tot=ptest.*s1;
plot(t,tot,'-g')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in your code for plotting.  You flipped `t` and `ptest` in your first `plot` call:

```
plot(ptest,t,'-ro');
```

This should be:

```
plot(t,ptest,'-ro');
```

The independent axis is time or `t`, but you have made that `ptest` instead.

When I flip this and run the code again, I get:

[image]

BTW, your question is a bit misleading.  I wouldn't call this "limiting"... you are actually *modulating* the amplitude of the sinusoidal signal with the amplitude of the `ptest` signal.